# Why does Swift use Linear probing on it's Dictionaries?

Tags: swift, algorithm, hashtable, computer-science

I was studying Computer Science when I found myself upon a question which I cannot get an answer to. Here's my train of thoughts so far:

- Hash tables using open addressing need a probing function to resolve collisions, such as linear / quadratic probing, or double hashing.
- Linear probing is prone to primary clustering on the hash tables which could lead to degraded performance (referencing MIT's algorithm [lecture](https://youtu.be/rvdJDijO2Ro?list=PLUl4u3cNGP61Oq3tWYp6V_F-5jb5L2iHb&t=1805))
- Found Swift's standard library uses Linear probing for it's Hash table implemention `Dictionary` ([source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift#L18))
- Then also learned that actually linear probing could be more performant(not sure) because of less cache misses ([Wikipedia on Linear probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing))

> Linear probing can provide high performance because of its good locality of reference, but is more sensitive to the quality of its hash function than some other collision resolution schemes.

- But other laguages like Golang seems to use quadratic probing on it's [hash tables](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/iface.go#L97)

So I'm confused on what's a good probing strategy on hash tables now and why the Swift team went ahead and used linear probing on it's Dictionaries. Any thoughts would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: "why the Swift team went ahead and used linear probing" -- only a member of the Swift team can answer that question.

Comment: Hi John, I do see that the implementation details could not be specifically answered until an Apple's engineer decides to shows up, but I'm merely trying to shed some light on the subject. I totally agree about the probing problem predating the creation of swift and found that NSDictionary also uses the same linear probing method (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379809/how-are-hash-collisions-handled)

Comment: If they had a good reason, my guess is that it's because linear probing is cache friendly. In a big hash table with small key-value pairs, you can probe several linear cells in the time that it would take to do another random access, so the simple theoretician's analysis misses the mark a bit. Clustering can be controlled with a good hash function (there's been significant improvement since linear hashing was proposed) and by decreasing the max load (which presents a space/time trade-off, though).